# empty date goes into database as 1970/01/01

Tags: php, mysql

So i have database column for date, however when a user leaves this section blank and updates a record it saves in the database as 1970/01/01.

[image]

Now when i make the columng null = no and default = none this does not work.

In my code i check to see if the value is null (which is why the strtotime() function fails). if it is null i try to set the value to be saved to ''.

```
        $niceDate = $this->judgement_date;
        $databaseDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($niceDate));
        if(is_null($databaseDate)){
            $databaseDate == '';
        }
        $this->judgement_date = $databaseDate;
```

Is there anyway for me to save an empty value of '' in the field or does the date type mean it has to have a value of a date format?

Comment: Whats the value of `$niceDate`

Comment: value of $niceDate is blank or null that's why its showing like this.

Comment: its the same date but in a different format. Basically the user wanted the data formated different so i make it look different on the front end but revert it back to the correct format for the database.

Comment: @JohnConde it will because i have tested and it reaches inside the if statement

Comment: check $niceDate I think the problem with this variable. if you didn't provide value in date() function then by default it return 1970/01/01.

Comment: I know it provides 1970/01/01 so i want it to change to '' instead

Comment: or the another possibility is that $niceDate contain time in Epoch format and when you pass an epoch format in strtotime() function then it always return the epoch value of date 1970/01/01

Comment: be careful, `null` and empty string `''` are two different things

Comment: yepp, thats why i check if its null and if its null i change it to an empty string so it saves in the database as an empty string instead of 1970/01/01

Comment: What format is your `$this->judgement_date` in. This looks like another `strtotime` American / European date format confusion to me

Comment: @MatthewSmart I think you're getting confused. You have a date type, an empty string will evaluate to the date you're seeing iirc. If you don't want a date at all, you need to insert a NULL for the column. Could be wrong.

Comment: I vote for confused. You are either setting the value to 1970 in code after pulling it from the db or before.

Answer (score 3):

*Assuming `$this->judgement_date` is in [a valid date format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)*, `$databaseDate` will never be null in your code as `strtotime()` and `date()` always return values (including `false`). You need to check if `$niceDate` has a valid value and then use an empty string if it does not.

You also use `==` instead of `=` as your assignment operator which is  a logical error that PHP will *not* report.

```
    $niceDate = $this->judgement_date;
    if(empty($databaseDate)){ // null is empty
        $databaseDate = '';
    }
    else {
        $databaseDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($niceDate));
    }
    $this->judgement_date = $databaseDate;
```

Comment: This saves it in the database as 1970/01/01 still

Comment: are you sure you do a insert with an empty string like: insert into TABLENAME (name,judgement_day) values ('tester','');

Comment: Well it must be haunted. Or maybe you're still setting the date using `date()` in another place in your code

Comment: **Will you please answer the question**: What format is your `$this->judgement_date` in please. if it is seperated by `/` American Date format is assumed. If it is seperated by `-` or `.` European format is assumed. If the date is in American format and seperated by a `-` then the MONTH can be seen as > 12 and therefore **INVALID** so `strtotime()` generates a duff date that equates to 1970/1/1